# Invoke Angular 4 root module on-demand through javascript

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am working on javascript web application which uses angular 4 components at certain places.

The way i invoke Angular 4 in my current web application is by placing the `<app-root></app-root>` inside the required div and loading the main.bundle.js (inline.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js, scripts.bundle.js,styles.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js are referenced in index.html). which work's perfect.

Now the problem which i am facing is, once i clear the innerHTML of the div which holds `<app-root></app-root>` and later repeat the process of placing the `<app-root></app-root>` inside the required div and loading the main.bundle.js it is not working(components are not loading).

Is there a way where i can solve this issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible...
Why don't you try to hide your "div" instead?

Comment: Well I founded how to do that. Check https://plnkr.co/edit/EwxZe5UlH1nsoIdzJvCp?p=preview

Comment: It doesn't work in PLunk but if you start app in your own server that it will working.